# how to show only strings matching the last line of an textarea

Tags: javascript

Why this doesn't work?
`txtags` is an textarea
`el` should be content of last line inside `txtags`
`poptag` are divs.

```
$('.txtags').keyup(function (event) {
    var el = $(this).val().split("\n").pop();
    el = el.trim();
    console.log(el);  // this works
    $('.poptag').hide();
    $('.poptag').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(el) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

For example, I type `abc` and expect `poptag` with text `abcx` should be shown, but - it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code should work as this is checking correctly for the last line in `textarea` with the content of `poptag`

```js
$('.txtags').keyup(function (event) {
    var el = $(this).val().split("\n").pop();
    el = el.trim();
    console.log(el);  // this works
    $('.poptag').hide();
    $('.poptag').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(el) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='txtags' ></textarea>
<div class='poptag'>this is me</div>
<div class='poptag'>apple ball </div>
<div class='poptag'>test for me</div>
```

Comment: I still cannot find the reason whi it is not working on my page, but anyway thanks a lot. let's say - solved.

Comment: In fact, where are `poptags` in your example?. Console.log works also in my case, but showing `poptags` - does not.